# ValidationFormula to include 2 datetime fields

Tags: list, development, validation

I have a custom list which is created via code. It has 2 fields for start and end date.

When I specify the `ValidationFormula` with the 2 fields, the code errors out.

Is there a way to validate the 2 fields without adding a custom form.

Comment: Can you include the formula in your post?

Comment: It is `[StartDate]<=[EndDate]`

Comment: Have you tried with = in front? "=[StartDate]<=[EndDate]"

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to move this formula validation from column level to list level. Thus all the columns are present at the list level.